# Difficulty creating custom RewriteRules for Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am creating a website for a radio station and want to make a section of the site for artists and tracks that are played on the radio. I am currently migrating the code I have written to a Wordpress template, and I'm having difficulty replicating the RewriteRules I have created.

I want a user to be able to type: 
`/music/<artist name here>/` 
`/music/<artist name here>/<track name here>/`

And have it rewrite to: 
`/music/artist.php?artist=<artist name here>` 
`/music/track.php?artist=<artist name here>&track=<track name here>`

e.g.: 
`/music/Red+Hot+Chili+Peppers/` 
`/music/Red+Hot+Chili+Peppers/Californication/`

I was able to achieve this using the following `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^music/([^/]*)/?$ /music/artist.php?artist=$1
RewriteRule ^music/([^/]*)/([^/]{1,})/?$ /music/track.php?artist=$1&track=$2
```

When I switched to Wordpress, I began by trying replicate the artist page first, and have been unable to do so.

Being that the structure of Wordpress is different from a standard directory/file structure, I decided to try two methods:

1. Rewrite to `/music/` for both of the rules, then decide to include either `artist.php` or `track.php` in the "music" page, based on the GET parameters.
2. Redirect to `/artist/` or `/track/` and have two different pages instead.

I have tried both methods and neither work.

For method 1, this is the code I added to `functions.php` (only trying the artist rewrite to begin with):

```
function custom_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_rule('music/([^/?]*)/?$', 'music/?artist=$1');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite');
```

Upon saving permalink settings (using "day and name"), this created the following `.htaccess` file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^music/([^/?]*)/?$ /music/?artist=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Upon navigating to `/music/<artist name here>/`, depending on different permalink settings, I will either get a 500 error or I will be shown the home page.

For method 2, this is the code I added to `functions.php`:

```
function custom_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_rule('music/([^/]*)/?$', 'artist/?artist=$1');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite');
```

Upon saving permalink settings (using "day and name"), this created the following `.htaccess` file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^music/([^/]*)/?$ /artist/?artist=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Again, upon navigating to `/music/<artist name here>/`, depending on different permalink settings, I will either get a 500 error or I will be shown the home page.

Is there something I'm missing in the `.htaccess` file? Am I somehow conflicting with Wordpress' permalink settings? Is this simply just not possible in Wordpress? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: These look like valid rules to me and in https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/. HTTP Error 500 can also mean that there is an error in your PHP. Can you turn on PHP startup errors and ensure that there isn't a problem in your artist.php or tracks.php script that is causing a 500? `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", true); ini_set("display_startup_errors", true);`

Comment: @GaryThomas I added that to my `functions.php` file. If I choose "day and name" in permalink settings, I get the following 500 error: https://imgur.com/jfzlc64

Comment: @GaryThomas checked the Apache error log and found the following:
`[Wed Aug 22 17:53:42.461954 2018] [core:error] [pid 14164:tid 1920] [client ::1:59489] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`
So perhaps a problem rewriting from /music/ to /music/? I will try this with method 2.

Comment: @GaryThomas Using method 2, I do not get the 500 error (suggesting I'm correct that I cannot rewrite from /music/ to /music/). However, I am instead simply shown the homepage. If I navigate to /artist/?artist=Artist+Name, I am shown the correct page (page-artist.php), so for some reason Wordpress is not showing the correct page template, or the rewrite is being ignored.